# How to know the right structure order?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, exam-questions

So I stumped upon this question using the right structure to complete the sentence

> One of the most ancient arts,___ in different parts of the world.
>
> (A) for weaving to develop independently
>   (B) the independent development of weaving
>   (C) weaving, to develop independently
>   (D) weaving developed independently

So the way I do this is to translate each option to my native language and choose the one that I found meaningful so I choose B but the correct one is D. Is there any structure order that I need to know instead of translating? Any help would be great

Comment: [correction: I am stumped by this question. :)]

Comment: The meaning is "Weaving [is] one of the most ancient arts. [It] developed independently in different parts of the world." I think what is confusing you is that the phrase describing weaving is placed at the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: This is a question about English grammar, so translating the sentence is unlikely to be a useful approach. Beyond "consider the rules of grammar you've learned in class," I'm not sure there's an answer to this question that's specific enough to be a good fir for this site.